# How to map values to a dictionary using multiple keys?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, mapping, data-science

I am trying to map values using the following dictionary:

```
color_class = {("red","maroon","burgundy"):"red hue",
           ("sky","turquoiseblue","darkblue","cyan","blue","royalblue"):"blue hue",
           ("lightpink","babypink","pink"):"pink hue",
           ("purple","mauve","violet"):"purple hue",
           ("green","seagreen","bluegreen","mint"):"green hue",
          ("brown"):"brown hue",
          ("yellow"):"yellow hue",
          ("orange"):"orange hue",
          ("black","white","grey"):"neutral hue",
          ("nocolor"):"none"}
```

I want the respective values in the dictionary to appear as a separate column(with heading "hue") in this dataframe:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the values in a dictionary you can use dict.values(). This will give you a list of the values in the dictionary.

You can add this as a column in a dataframe. You can do it one step like in the examplebelow.

```
 df['hue'] = color_class.values()
```